# Teradata error "Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group"

Tags: sql, teradata

```
>SELECT sku, jun_sale, jul_sale, aug_sale, (jun_sale + jul_sale + aug_sale) 
>AS total_sale,
>CASE 
>when EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate)=6 AND stype= 'P'
>then sum(amt)
>end as jun_sale,
>CASE
>when EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate)=7 AND stype= 'P'
>then sum(amt)
>end as jul_sale,
>CASE
>when EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate)=8 AND stype= 'P'
>then sum(amt)
>end as aug_sale
>FROM trnsact
>group by 1
>order by total_sale;
```

> Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group

Can someone find out what is the error in the case?

Comment: sku, jun_sale, jul_sale, aug_sale must be part of the group by

Comment: since your suming(amt) conditionally, all the other fields not aggregated in the select must be part of the group by so group by `sku, jun_sale, jul_sale, aug_sale, (jun_sale + jul_sale + aug_sale) as total_sale,` not just 1

Comment: This is a Teradata error, why do you tag `mysql`?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to SUM over CASE:

```
select sku,
   sum(case 
         when EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate)=6 AND stype= 'P'
         then amt
       end) as jun_sale,
   sum(case 
         when EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate)=7 AND stype= 'P'
         then amt
       end) as jul_sale,
   sum(case 
         when EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate)=8 AND stype= 'P'
         then amt
       end) as aug_sale,
   jun_sale + jul_sale + aug_sale as total_sale
from trnsact
group by 1
order by total_sale;
```

And you should add a WHERE-condition restricting to rows from June to August.

Edit:

If an item was not sold in any of the three months you will get a NULL (and then the `total_sale` calculation will also result in NULL). You can add `else 0` to each CASE to get zeroes instead.

Comment: Thanks dnoeth, it worked but not getting total sales.

Comment: @DaulatDaga: Well, how do you define *total sales*, currently it's the sum of those three months ?